# How to filter all the fields based on one field in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct, filter, uisearchbar

when I filter a field other fields in the structure are not getting filtered

```
 struct Objects {
                 var sectionName : String!
                 var sectionObjects : [String] 
                 var sectionid:[String]!
                 var sectionph:[String]!
                 var sectionImage:[String]!
                    }

            var objectArray = [Objects]()
            var objectArrayFilter = [Objects]()


       objectArrayFilter = objectArray.flatMap{
                var filterObjects = $0
                print(filterObjects)
                filterObjects.sectionObjects = $0.sectionObjects.filter {
                    //print($0.sectionObjects.filter)
                    $0.range(of : searchBar.text!, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
                }
                return filterObjects.sectionObjects.isEmpty ? nil : filterObjects


            }
```

I need to get only sonam id but every ones id in the section is coming

```
.Objects(sectionName: S, sectionObjects: ["Sonam"], sectionid: ["4", "2", "5"], sectionph: ["", "8086285424", ""], sectionImage: ["", "http://www.***.com/**/images/participant/SintoSep_04_2017_09:43:482.jpg", ""])]
```

Answer (score 0):

you say you only want the section names.. im not sure what you mean so I wrote what I think is likely...

#### only get section names (map structs and filter, you could keep objects if you let out the map directly)

```
let sectionNames = objectArray.map {
    return $0.sectionName
}
let filteredItems = sectionNames.filter {
    return $0.range(of : searchBar.text!, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
}
let selectedSectionNames = filteredItems.isEmpty ?? sectionNames
```

I dont get why you do the flatMap at the beginning. are the sections somehow nested in that case?

Comment: .I need to get the filter output like .Objects(sectionName: S, sectionObjects: ["Sonam"], sectionid: [ "2"], sectionph: ["8086285424"], sectionImage: ["http://www.***.com/**/images/participant/SintoSep_04_2017_09:43:482.jpg", ""])] after filter but I am getting .Objects(sectionName: S, sectionObjects: ["Sonam"], sectionid: ["4", "2", "5"], sectionph: ["", "8086285424", ""], sectionImage: ["", "http://www.***.com/**/images/participant/SintoSep_04_2017_09:43:482.jpg", ""])]    ,its  a search for table view  section names are alphabets A-Z

Comment: Then above is right except u loose the map and filter on $0.sectionName

Comment: its not working this is my functionobjectArrayFilter = objectArray.flatMap{
                var filterObjects = $0
               
                
                filterObjects.sectionObjects = $0.sectionObjects.filter {
                    //print($0.sectionObjects.filter)
                    $0.range(of : searchBar.text!, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
                } it only filters section objects I need the currospoing sessionsid sessionph and session image in object array filter